# Angular 4 Material validator

Tags: angular, validation, angular-material

I started create form:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.pointForm = new FormGroup({
      X: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, this.ValidatorX]),
      Y: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, this.ValidatorY]),
    })
  }
```

Fragment of my HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
<input type="text" name="X" id="X"
                         placeholder="X" matInput [(ngModel)]="X"
                         formControlName="X" (blur)="transformCoordinates(); ifXisBlur()" (click)="outputCoordinateX()"
                         required>
                  <mat-error *ngIf="pointForm.get('X').errors && pointForm.get('X').errors['required']">Required</mat-error>
                  <mat-error *ngIf="pointForm.get('X').errors && pointForm.get('X').errors['unproper']">Unproper</mat-error>

    </mat-form-field>
```

I define two variables, which check correctness:

```
validX: string = '10';
validY: string = '10';
```

I created my own validators: ValidatorX and ValidatorY. It should return error, when varible validX or validY is 0:

```
ValidatorX(): ValidationErrors{
    if (this.validX === '0'){
      return {unproper: true};
    }
  }

  ValidatorY(): ValidationErrors {
    if (this.validY === '0'){
      return {unproper: true};
    }
  }
```

In my project I have a function, which check value of X and Y (this function is very complicated, for the occasion of this question, I simplified it):

```
transformCoordinates() {
    let X = this.pointForm.value.X;
    let Y = this.pointForm.value.Y;

    if (Y >= -90) {
      this.validY = '1';
      if (X >= -180) {
        this.validX = '1';
      }
      else {
        this.validX = '0';
      }
    }
    else {
      this.validY = '0';
    }
  }
```

When I started my application I have an error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'validX' of undefined`

I don't understand, why?
At the very beginning, I specifically defined the values of these variables as string '10'

Comment: This is being asked twice a day in one form or another. replace `[Validators.required, this.ValidatorX]` by `[Validators.required, control => this.ValidatorX(control)]. You shouldn't access `this` to get the value of the control anyway. You should get it from the FormControl passed as argument of your validator. This would also have the additional advantage of being able to use the same validator for both fields.

Comment: Now I have en error: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1. I supose I should do something more in code, but I don't understand what.

Comment: Read my comment again. Your validators are supposed to take a FormControl as argument. And you're supposed to get the value to validate from that argument. https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators, https://angular.io/api/forms/ValidatorFn

Comment: I think You don't understand my question. Maybe I can't precisely describe the problem. I try one more time: I don't want to use control in my validator. I want use global variable - validX. This variable is used in external function-
 transformCoordinates(). When the event in the function (e.g X<-180) will set the variable this.validX = '0' then I want to display the validation.